# What is wireframe-esque design style called? Is it made solely with pen tool?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, vector, path

Wondering what this wireframe like designing style is called. I've seen it for years but never really felt the urge to ask. I also wish to know if it is made solely with the pen tool in ps/ai or if it is a differing method ie.very precise stroke manipulation through multiple layers from an original image be it a 3d render or real life product shot. I honestly don't know how I don't know the specific term used for it seeing as how it is so popular within my community (although mainly mobile and desktop devices).

Thanks for any help you guys can give!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are merely line art illustrations. You can easily do these with any number of applications. My choice would be Illustrator.

There is no actual 3D there it's all just drawn.

That being posted, you *could* use some CAD software and it's isometric or 3d tools, but that's not at all required.

Comment: Another word would be "traced", but this is correct. An interesting animated example was made for [Polygon's PlayStation 4 Review and Xbox One Review](http://product.voxmedia.com/2013/11/25/5426880/polygon-feature-design-svg-animations-for-fun-and-profit). Neat article

Comment: Just line art with an animated revealing mask @ZachSaucier :) Still merely line art though.

Answer (score 1):

Line illustration is fine but I would say that this style is called drafted. Reason being that this is exactly the kind of output one gets from designers of physical objects that still use 2d blueprints. So you could also call this blueprint or perhaps manual style too.

[image: 2D output form my 3D CAD]

**Image 1:** A 2D line projection (draft, technical drawing) of a spare 3D part that i had toyed with earlier today.

Whether or not is 3D depends on what the person who made the image was using. It might be 2D or it might not its hard to tell.